# Using the IE8 'Developer Tools' to debug earlier IE versions

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, firebug

I am less than satisfied in my HTML/CSS/JS debugging of pages with IE6 and 7 specific bugs.

I am aware that IE8 has a Firebug clone, called 'Developer Tools' installed.

Is it possible to have IE8 installed (maybe on a VM, i don't mind), set it to compatibility mode (is there one for IE6?), then perform JS debugging and live HTML changes, **using the IE8 Developer Tools**, just like we can in Firebug?

many many thanks
mieze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are differences between native IE6/7 and the IE8 compatibility mode:
http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/03/12/site-compatibility-and-ie8.aspx

The best option I've found to debug in IE6/7 is to install the Microsoft Script Editor (not Debugger), that is bundled with Microsoft Office. It's an optional install, so you probably have to open Add remove programs in Control panel and go through setup again. Here's a guide to configure IE after you've installed the Microsoft Script Editor.
http://www.jonathanboutelle.com/mt/archives/2006/01/howto_debug_jav.html

The default view doesn't have breakpoints and such, so take a look at the menu to add the views you like. It's not as good as Firebug, but it's a lot better than alert-debugging ;)

Answer (score 3):

I've said it before, and I'll say it again:

[Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html)

That'll let you use Firebug features in whatever browser you feel like using that day...

Comment: Problem with firebug lite is that it doesn't like frames (firebug has a few frames bugs as well, nothing like Lite though). Yes, the app I'm developing uses frames...

Comment: You might want to give the old IE Developer Toolbar a shot then if you haven't already... http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en

Comment: unfortunately the IE dev toolbar doesn't do JS debugging.

Answer (score 3):

The most satisfying IE6/7/8 javascript debugging experience I've had is with Visual Studio. And you don't have to shell out the beaucoup bucks to get it either since the Express edition has the same debugger as the higher SKUs.

1. Install Visual Studio Express Edition ([Download](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/.))
2. Create a new project
3. Click debug to start the empty project
4. You now have an instance of IE running in a world class debugger!

Just point the browser at your test URL and set breakpoints to your hearts content!

Comment: also, the IE App Compatibility Virtual Machine images in combination with this technique are quite helpful: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en

Comment: think you mean "beaucoup bucks" :) http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=beaucoup%20(also%20spelled%20boocoo)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try MS javascript debugger http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2f465be0-94fd-4569-b3c4-dffdf19ccd99&displaylang=en
Not without its share of problems though

Answer (score 0):

The IE8 dev tools is an upgrade of the [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en), which is available for 6 & 7. It doesn't do debugging, but will let you inspect the DOM, etc. Combining it with the JS debugger (as in other answers) is as good as you can get, afaik