# Print content of JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, object

Typically if we just use `alert(object);` it will show as `[object Object]`.  How to print all the content parameters of an object in JavaScript?

Answer (score 330, accepted):

If you are using Firefox, `alert(object.toSource())` should suffice for simple debugging purposes.

Comment: Also supported in IE9 (if not earlier), but not by Chrome 17 or Safari 5.

Comment: Is there a cross-browser way of doing something similar?

Comment: In recent browsers, you can use `console.dir(object)` to dump the contents of an object to the debugging console (F12 on most browsers).

Comment: I was trying to use this in console.log(object.toSource()); didn't work for me..

Comment: With firefox quantum 58, object.toSource() is slowing down the browser extremely. It might be my object (json string), but it shouldn't happen. EDIT: i'ts actually a cyclic object value. JSON.stringify() sends warning to console, which is better than the .toSource() behavior (no warning, semi-freezing)

Comment: Best answer is the one that uses `console.dir(object)`, as it works for most modern browsers and takes care of cyclic references too. Plus 1 for the user who mentioned it. Thank you!

Comment: @BinitaBharati well, I answered this in 2009 when console.dir did not exist ... maybe in 2037, console.dir would no longer be the best ..

Answer (score 806):

This will give you very nice output with an indented JSON object using `JSON.stringify`:

```js
alert(JSON.stringify(YOUR_OBJECT_HERE, null, 4));
```

The second argument (`replacer`) alters the contents of the string before returning it.

The third argument (`space`) specifies how many spaces to use as white space for readability.

`JSON.stringify` documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: +1 for cross-platform support.
Standardized in ECMAScript 5th Edition, with support in Firefox 3.6, Chrome (ver?), Safari 4, and IE8.

FYI: The 4 parameter is the number of spaces for each indention level.  It may also be a string, e.g. "\t".
The null parameter is a placeholder for a filtering function, if you want to limit what gets shown.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: endlessly useful in the IE8 JS debugger.

Comment: This doesn't work for objects with circular reference chains - Chrome gives an error: TypeError: Converting curcular structure to JSON

Comment: I'm seeing this same circular structure error in Chrome:  `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this endemic to Chrome?

Comment: Nice answer. You saved my day, I'm using this in Phonegap.

Comment: You may use https://www.npmjs.org/package/json-stringify-safe to avoid circular reference issues.

Answer (score 79):

Aside from using a debugger, you can also access all elements of an object using a `foreach` loop. The following `printObject` function should `alert()` your object showing all properties and respective values.

```
function printObject(o) {
  var out = '';
  for (var p in o) {
    out += p + ': ' + o[p] + '\n';
  }
  alert(out);
}

// now test it:
var myObject = {'something': 1, 'other thing': 2};
printObject(myObject);
```

Using a DOM inspection tool is preferable because it allows you to dig under the properties that are objects themselves. Firefox has FireBug but all other major browsers (IE, Chrome, Safari) also have debugging tools built-in that you should check.

Comment: Might want to add if (o.hasOwnProperty(p)) inside the loop

Comment: That's a good idea, but when debugging I'd rather see it all. Perhaps even better would be something like:
for (var p in o) {
 if (!o.hasOwnProperty(p)) out += '(inherited) ';
 out += p + ': ' + o[p] + '\n';
}

Answer (score 33):

If you just want to have a string representation of an object, you could use the `JSON.stringify` function, using a [JSON library](http://json.org/js.html).

Comment: this is the best answer IMHO, it works across browsers

Answer (score 17):

You could Node's [util.inspect(object)](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) to print out object's structure.

It is especially helpful when your object has circular dependencies e.g.

```
$ node

var obj = {
   "name" : "John",
   "surname" : "Doe"
}
obj.self_ref = obj;

util = require("util");

var obj_str = util.inspect(obj);
console.log(obj_str);
// prints { name: 'John', surname: 'Doe', self_ref: [Circular] }
```

It that case JSON.stringify throws exception: `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Comment: Thank. This can be used in places where printing goes to the logs.

Answer (score 14):

Print content of object you can use

```
console.log(obj_str);
```

you can see the result in console like below.

```
Object {description: "test"}
```

For open console press F12 in chrome browser, you will found console tab in debug mode.

Answer (score 8):

You should consider using [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) for JavaScript debugging. It will let you interactively inspect all of your variables, and even step through functions.

Answer (score 7):

Use dir(object). Or you can always download [Firebug for Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/) (really helpful).

Comment: dir? need include any special js file?

Comment: its only needs the firebug extension

Comment: console.dir(object)  Prints output in Firebug's Console pane.  Returns "_firebugIgnore", so it's not for use with alert().
Documented at http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.dir.28object.29

Answer (score 3):

Javascript for all!

```
String.prototype.repeat = function(num) {
    if (num < 0) {
        return '';
    } else {
        return new Array(num + 1).join(this);
    }
};

function is_defined(x) {
    return typeof x !== 'undefined';
}

function is_object(x) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === "[object Object]";
}

function is_array(x) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === "[object Array]";
}

/**
 * Main.
 */
function xlog(v, label) {
    var tab = 0;

    var rt = function() {
        return '    '.repeat(tab);
    };

    // Log Fn
    var lg = function(x) {
        // Limit
        if (tab > 10) return '[...]';
        var r = '';
        if (!is_defined(x)) {
            r = '[VAR: UNDEFINED]';
        } else if (x === '') {
            r = '[VAR: EMPTY STRING]';
        } else if (is_array(x)) {
            r = '[\n';
            tab++;
            for (var k in x) {
                r += rt() + k + ' : ' + lg(x[k]) + ',\n';
            }
            tab--;
            r += rt() + ']';
        } else if (is_object(x)) {
            r = '{\n';
            tab++;
            for (var k in x) {
                r += rt() + k + ' : ' + lg(x[k]) + ',\n';
            }
            tab--;
            r += rt() + '}';
        } else {
            r = x;
        }
        return r;
    };

    // Space
    document.write('\n\n');

    // Log
    document.write('< ' + (is_defined(label) ? (label + ' ') : '') + Object.prototype.toString.call(v) + ' >\n' + lg(v));
};



// Demo //

var o = {
    'aaa' : 123,
    'bbb' : 'zzzz',
    'o' : {
        'obj1' : 'val1',
        'obj2' : 'val2',
        'obj3' : [1, 3, 5, 6],
        'obj4' : {
            'a' : 'aaaa',
            'b' : null
        }
    },
    'a' : [ 'asd', 123, false, true ],
    'func' : function() {
        alert('test');
    },
    'fff' : false,
    't' : true,
    'nnn' : null
};

xlog(o, 'Object'); // With label
xlog(o); // Without label

xlog(['asd', 'bbb', 123, true], 'ARRAY Title!');

var no_definido;
xlog(no_definido, 'Undefined!');

xlog(true);

xlog('', 'Empty String');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Prototype's Object.inspect() method, which "Returns the debug-oriented string representation of the object".

http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Object/inspect/

Comment: Its quite unhelpful for a javascript library to call itself after a fundamental aspect of a language.

Answer (score 2):

You can give your objects their own toString methods in their prototypes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use json.js from http://www.json.org/js.html to change json data to string data.

Answer (score 2):

Simple function to alert contents of an object or an array .
Call this function with an array or string or an object it alerts the contents.

**Function**

```
function print_r(printthis, returnoutput) {
    var output = '';

    if($.isArray(printthis) || typeof(printthis) == 'object') {
        for(var i in printthis) {
            output += i + ' : ' + print_r(printthis[i], true) + '\n';
        }
    }else {
        output += printthis;
    }
    if(returnoutput && returnoutput == true) {
        return output;
    }else {
        alert(output);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
print_r(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 8 has developer tools which is similar to [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for Firefox. Opera has Opera DragonFly, and Google Chrome also has something called Developer Tools (Shift+Ctrl+J).

Here is more a more detailed answer to debug JavaScript in IE6-8:
[Using the IE8 'Developer Tools' to debug earlier IE versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780059/using-the-ie8-developer-tools-to-debug-earlier-ie-versions/801547#801547)

Answer (score -6):

I faced similar problem, The reason for it was i make use of ajax to fetch data.
In this case i had made two asynchronous ajax call. In one i just return string msg and show in alert. In second ajax call i fetch arraylist in json format and decode it in js.
So my second request use to process first and i was getting alert of object.

So just check.
1. alert should contain string.
2. If u get arrayList or any other Object decode it.

All the best!