# JSON - How to merge nested object inside array in php

Tags: php, json

Hi I want to put json nested object with this format:

```
[{"lat":-6.92015,"lon":107.67024,"value":0.1},{"lat":-6.88283,"lon":107.60149,"value":0.1},..]
```

into this json array :

```
{"max": 30, "data": [...]}
```

and will result in this format :

```
{"max": 30, "data": [{"lat":-6.92015,"lon":107.67024,"value":0.1},...]}
```

my current code :

```
$data[] = array(lat=>(float)$row["geo_lat"], lon=>(float)$row["geo_long"], value=>1);
$post_data = json_encode(array('max' => 30, 'data' => $data));
echo $post_data;
```

How I can do that? Thanks

Comment: What's the problem with what you have?

Comment: No problems man, sorry for that, I've syntax error on that line, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
$array = json_decode('[{"lat":-6.92015,"lon":107.67024,"value":0.1},{"lat":-6.88283,"lon":107.60149,"value":0.1}]');

print_r($array);

$final_array = array('max'=>30,'data'=>$array);
print_r($final_array);

$output = json_encode($final_array);
print $output;
```

Code in action: [eval.in](http://eval.in/31706)

Comment: May I ask you a questions, when I call `alert(data)` after success response in ajax, why the result represented with [object][object] sometime `undefined`? this is a correct output? thanks

Comment: check this post to print objects: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625208/print-content-of-javascript-object`