# JavaScript return object

Tags: javascript, object, logging, console, return

I am digging into some JavaScript at the moment and I have a given function from which I want to return an object similar to HashMap. Here are the contents of the function:

```
function(video){
    var obj = {"title":video.title, "id":video.id};
    console.log(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

The problem is that the console.log prints the correct values, but the return does not return them. Here is an example output:

console.log:

```
{title: "Die Hard", id: 2}
{title: "Avatar", id: 3}
```

return:

```
{[Object]}
{[Object]}
```

Comment: Have you tried a console.log with the returned value? I am pretty sure it is OK.

Comment: When I tried console.log for the returned object, it showed correct output

Comment: In addition to answer below, instead of alerts or adding html to get a better look at an obj, you can pretty print too: `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are alerting the results to the screen.

```
function video(){
  return {title: "Die Hard", id: 2}
}

a = video();

console.log(a); // Object {title: "Die Hard", id: 2}
alert(a); // [object Object]
```

You can read up on why that is, as well as possible solutions here: [Print content of JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625208/print-content-of-javascript-object)

However, the bottom line is: just use `console.log()` to inspect objects (and anything else really).

Comment: Nope, I just map the object to another variable and use console.log() to print it.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: That works as expected for me. `videoIdAndBookmarkIdPairs` returns an array of objects. Initially this looks like `[Object, Object]` on the console, but if you click the triangle of the left of it, you can unfold it and explore the array's contents. If you want to see everything contained in the array in one go, @Todd's tip is a good one. `console.log(JSON.stringify(videoIdAndBookmarkIdPairs, undefined, 2));` will format the contents of the array nicely.

Comment: Yes, stringify showed me the information in the objects, cheers!

Comment: No probs. If that helped, maybe you could accept the answer.