# print properties and values of an object at the same time-Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-5

Assuming we have the following Javascript Object

```
var t={name:"John",age:34,zip:"82900"}
```

If I use the following code to print all properties of that object:

```
for(var x in t){
console.log(t[x]);
}
```

I will get John, 34, 82900.Now my question is how to to print each propertie's name
for example to print age,34 name,John
that object might have more properties than i wrote above since the user can add its own properties inside that object

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print content of JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625208/print-content-of-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var t = { name : "John", age : 34, zip : "82900" };

for(var x in t){
  console.log(x, t[x]);
}
```