# How to print all the properties of the object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

```
var object = { name: 'Harry', age: '25', sex: 'male'...... n};
```

This object has 'n' number of properties which I don't know and I would like to print these whole properties.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Object.keys() ...

Answer (score 48):

There are heaps of solutions from a quick Google, a recomended result is; [Print content of JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625208/print-content-of-javascript-object)

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(object, null, 4));
```

> The second argument alters the contents of the string before returning it. The third argument specifies how many spaces to use as white space for readability.

Comment: This fails for objects with cycles in their membership.

Answer (score 29):

You can use the The `Object.keys()` function to get an array of the properties of the object:

```js
var obj = { name: 'Harry', age: '25', sex: 'male'};
Object.keys(obj).forEach((prop)=> console.log(prop));
```

Comment: that's too many console.log's; better collect that into a string.