# javascript alert prints Object Object

Tags: javascript, json

this is my code which prints below output on the alert.

```
alert(JSON.stringify( args.errors,null,4));
```

this is the output.

```
{
    "Weight":{
        "errors":[
            "Hello My name is John"
        ]
    }
}
```

I just want "Hello My name is john" in the alert box. Any help will be great

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print content of JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625208/print-content-of-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `args.Weight.errors.join(', ')` to alert the errors.

In case if there is only one error, it will be shown. Otherwise, all the errors will be separated by `,`.

I am assuming you are having

```js
let args = {
    "Weight":{
        "errors":[
            "Hello My name is John"
        ]
    }
};

alert(args.Weight.errors.join(', '));
```

It should work.

Comment: @TusharJangade you need to join the errors, so, `args.Weight.errors.join(', ')`

Comment: thank you guys it was args.errors.Weight.errors.join(', ') that solved my error. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume the output you mentioned is the error data and you want to display the errors from the that.

```
const data = {
    Weight: {
      errors: ["Hello My name is John"]
    }
};
```

To alert the users with above data you can use

```
alert(data.Weight.errors[0])
```

Test at snippet at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-matsumoto-n5ste)

Answer (score 1):

If `args` is your object, you could simply alert `args.Weight.errors` and, in case there is more than one error, add [`join(', ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to list them separated by `,`.

```js
let args = {
  "Weight": {
    "errors": [
      "Hello My name is John"
    ]
  }
};
alert(args.Weight.errors.join(', '));
```

Comment: this code solved my error. thank you so much for this. @AlessioCantarella