# Javscript returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following PHP code on `countries.php`.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM countries");
$stmt-> execute();

$data = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
  $data[] = array(
    'id' => $row['id'],
    'name' => $row['name']
  );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

And following JS in `onboard.js`

```
$.ajax({
  url: "processes/countries.php",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(countriesList) {
    var questions = [
      {
        question: "What's your country?", 
        type: "select", 
        // response : ['India', 'America', 'Japan']
        response: $.each(countriesList, function(){ 
          this.name; // DISPLAYS [object Object]
        })
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

As you can see I am trying to get the list of countries and display it. However, `countriesList` in jquery code here returns `[object Object]`. How can I get the response to print the countries names?

[image]

Network tab response shows data is returned in the following manner:

```
[
  {"id":"1","name":"Afghanistan"},
  {"id":"2","name":"Albania"},
  {"id":"3","name":"Algeria"},
  {"id":"4","name":"American Samoa"},
]
```

The data given above is taken after switching to the `RAW` format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print content of JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625208/print-content-of-javascript-object)

Comment: Change to console.log(countriesList);

Comment: @mplungjan the actual problem is in response part of the questions array and not in the alert.

Comment: What is `questions[0].response` supposed to be?

Comment: @VladimirKornea List of countries in select box.. I have updated a sample response in the question. Please check for the commented response part.

Comment: I mean what do you expect `console.log(questions[0].response)` to print?

Comment: @VladimirKornea If you would have read the question well you would have understood it. Anyways, thanks for your time. I really appreciate it. And do checkout accepted answer by Rinshan Kolayil.

Comment: The problem WAS the alert since the toString of your object was not useful. Using console.log, you will get a better representation and you would see the structure of the returned object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var questions = [{
    question: "What's your country?",
    type: "select",
    response: countriesList.map(function(elem) {
        return elem.name;
    })
    // response: countriesList.map(function(elem) {
    //     return '<option value="'+elem.name+'">'+elem.name+'</option>';
    // }).join("")
}]
```

Comment: If you wish to have names of country as array, can you please try above code, i updated. Or can you please tell which structure you with to see the output

Comment: Perfect.. That's what I was looking for all this time.. So that's how it works. Thanks man! Saved my day :)

Comment: For your answer update, I actually only needed what you gave earlier. The `commented` part is not required. I am defining the `<select>` tag somewhere else later in the JS code. But let that be here in the answer, someone else might benefit with the `commented` part of your answer.