# How can I test on IE8 after installing IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I need to test javascript on IE8 but since I updated I cannot install IE8. What do developers do in this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the IE8 'Developer Tools' to debug earlier IE versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780059/using-the-ie8-developer-tools-to-debug-earlier-ie-versions)

Comment: Developer tools can simulate **some** of the functionality but really you need a full install as the dev tools aren't 100%. Something like [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/) or a VM

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way is having multiple virtual machines installed on your computer (or on a testingstation) that run different windows versions and IE versions.

There is no way to install IE8 or multiple IE versions at the same time on one windows installation.

You find all windows versions and IE versions [here](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/) and also some instructions how to set up the virtual machines.

Another way is to use the tool [IETester](http://ietester.de.softonic.com/), which only runs on windows and kind of simulates different IE's. It never really felt reliable to me.

There are also different companies, which provide multi-browser testing suites. They allow you to remotely test browsers (including IE8) remotely on their servers. For example [Browserling](https://www.browserling.com/) or [Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Use a VM! Get something like virtualbox and you can get the box from Microsoft https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/

You can use the emulator built into 11 but know that it's not a direct emulation and isn't the *real* thing. A VM will create a new machine that is running a paired down version of windows and the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the developer tools there is a button on the top right corner which allows you to run the browser as an older version of IE:

[image]

Comment: Not a trustworthy simulation.

Comment: still a useful tool for testing IMO, which is what he is asking for

Comment: I don't think it is worth to fool yourself that things are alright. It is a bad thing to do, because instead of IE8 behavior you will get IE11-8 behavior that is completely different from IE8. It will make you lose time at the end.

Comment: You can visit this link https://www.browserstack.com/test-in-internet-explorer   which allows you to test even more versions.